# SSIS Custom transformation receive variable

Tags: c#, variables, ssis, global-variables, custom-component

I am creating a custom transformation in C# to be used in SSIS. I have already been able creating and adding the custom component and receive and alter data from a db source but I need more data to register in a log table. This data can only be passed with variables but I can't find a good explanation of how to add a `readonlyvariable` to my component.

I have tried to use *IDTSVariable100* and *VariableDispenser* but I can't make sense of how to.

```
 public override void ProvideComponentProperties()
                    {
                        base.ProvideComponentProperties();
                        base.RemoveAllInputsOutputsAndCustomProperties();
                        VariableDispenser varDispenser = this.VariableDispenser();

                        IDTSVariable100 vr = this.VariableDispenser.GetVariables();
                        IDTSInput100 input = this.ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.New();
                        input.Name = "Input_B";

                        IDTSOutput100 output=this.ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.New();
                        output.Name = "Output_B";

                        // the output is synchronous with the input
                        output.SynchronousInputID = input.ID;

                     }
```

Basically i want to define `readonlyvariables` that I can alter the value before my custom component runs like the original "script component" has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i researched a bit more and stumbled on a answer:
It seems that to access the SSIS public variables we have to get them with code on the ProcessInput Method:

```
var dimSrcId ="";

IDTSVariables100 variables = null;

this.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::dimSrcId");

this.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(out variables);

dimSrcId = variables["User::dimSrcId"].Value.ToString();

variables.Unlock();
```

By using the **VariableDispenser.LockForRead()** we're capable of searching for our variables and access there value.