# How can use read and write variable in ssis script component?

Tags: ssis

I'm new in ssis and want  to pass read and write variable to the script component,for that purpose, define variable in script editor windows:
[image]

and in the script write this code for use that:
[image]

but when run that data flow,i get this error:

[image]

How can i solve that problem?search on the web i did not understand anything.thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that you can use variables from **ReadWriteVariables** only at **PostExecute** method, for example, to save your counter value. If you need to read this variable before **PostExecute** method, you can specify it as **ReadOnlyVariables**. Caveat - you can choose only one of the collections, not both. This is by Microsoft design.
If you need to have read access to a read-write variable earlier that **PostExecute**, you can call VariableDispenser [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32229160/1010622). But in this case you **have to exclude** this variable from both **ReadOnlyVariables** and **ReadWriteVariables** lists.